# Using mock to test if directory exists or not

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I have been exploring mock and pytest for a few days now.

I have the following method:

```
def func():
    if not os.path.isdir('/tmp/folder'):
        os.makedirs('/tmp/folder')
```

In order to unit test it, I have decided to patch os.path.isdir and os.makedirs, as shown:

```
@patch('os.path.isdir')
@patch('os.makedirs')
def test_func(patch_makedirs, patch_isdir):
    patch_isdir.return_value = False
    assert patch_makedirs.called == True
```

The assertion fails, irrespective of the return value from patch_isdir. Can someone please help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Can't say for sure having the complete code, but I have the feeling it's related to [where you're patching](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch).

You should patch the `os` module that was imported by the module under test.

So, if you have it like this:

*mymodule.py*:

```
def func():
    if not os.path.isdir('/tmp/folder'):
        os.makedirs('/tmp/folder')
```

you should make your _test_mymodule.py_ like this:

```
@patch('mymodule.os')
def test_func(self, os_mock):
    os_mock.path.isdir.return_value = False
    assert os_mock.makedirs.called
```

Note that this specific test is not that useful, since it's essentially testing if the module `os` works -- and you can probably assume that is well tested. ;)

Your tests would probably be better if focused on your application logic (maybe, the code that calls `func`?).

Comment: I am using a similar os mock, but if I compare it with this example, I'd say in my code, `os.mkdirs` is being called twice, so I have to assert the same that it's being called twice, but if I get it's call count, its `0` So I am not able to use, 
assert `os_mock.mkdirs.get.call_count == 2`
Could you please suggest where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the call to func().

```
@patch('os.path.isdir')
@patch('os.makedirs')
def test_func(patch_makedirs, patch_isdir):
    patch_isdir.return_value = False
    yourmodule.func()
    assert patch_makedirs.called == True
```